# `tqdm` wrapper for function with while loop

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, tqdm

I have a long-standing library function I cannot edit that runs a while loop and returns a value. In essence, something like this:

```py
import time

def myfunc():
    i = 0
    while i < 5 * 1000:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
    return i
```

Is there a way I can wrap this function, perhaps in a decorator, in such a way that it can be passed to `tqdm` and spit out a progress bar? I'm not quite sure how I would achieve this since I cannot edit the code inside `myfunc`.

My goal is to make a progress bar for `myfunc` without touching it. Does anyone have any suggestsions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *legal* ways to do that, unless this function returns an Iterable/Generator. But, of course, you might to launch that function in a thread, and just simulate loading by doing something like

```py
import time, tqdm, concurrent

def myfunc():
    i = 0
    while i < 5 * 1000:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
    return i


def simulate_loading(background_function):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(background_function)
        while not future.done():
            yield
            time.sleep(0.05)
        return future.result()

for _ in tqdm.tqdm(simulate_loading(myfunc)):
    pass
```

```
115it [00:05, 19.85it/s]
```

Comment: Btw, thanks for introducing `tqdm`, I didn't know about such convenient lib for drawing progress bars :)

Comment: I'm glad! Happy to help!